# MySQL JSON key value pair to table

Tags: mysql, json, key

for first stage i suggest that json not nested - plain pairs key-value packed from post request by php script and passed as single json-type parameter to mysql stored procedure - i need get table where two columns - key and corresponding value

```sql
set @j:='{"customer_name":"Ворпенсий", "customer_bd":"1952-10-07"}';
select *, json_unquote(json_extract(@j, concat('$.', `name`))) as `value`
from json_table(json_keys(@j), 
              "$[*]" columns(name varchar(100) path "$")) as jt;
```

code work as expected but how can i join this 2-step solution to 1-step?

Comment: Some sample data would help answer the question.

Comment: updated code with json-variable

Comment: updated code with json_unquote

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is probably close to optimal. You could also achieve the same result by joining two `JSON_TABLEs`, one of keys and the other of values. For example:

```sql
SELECT name, value
FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(@j),
    "$[*]" COLUMNS (
          rn FOR ORDINALITY,
          name VARCHAR(100) PATH '$'
          )
    ) n
JOIN JSON_TABLE(@j, 
    "$.*" COLUMNS (
          rn FOR ORDINALITY,
          value VARCHAR(100) PATH '$'
          )
    ) v ON n.rn = v.rn
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
name            value
customer_bd     1952-10-07
customer_name   Ворпенсий
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6e9fd5e06d4aae201c7c45233f12d93)

Comment: thank you very much for support & link to dbfiddle

Comment: @СлаваСедов no worries - I hope you find it useful.