# Concatenate JSON array to a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am looking for a way to concatenate a JSON array in MySQL to a delimited string.

Here is an example that uses nested `REPLACE()` functions to replace characters in the string.

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_KEYS('{
  "foo": "I am foo",
  "bar": "I am bar",
  "baz": "I am baz"
}'), '["', ''), '", "', '|'), '"]', '') AS value;
```

returns...

```
bar|baz|foo
```

Is there a native way to do this that does not involve doing something quite as hacky?

Comment: No, not in MySQL. Fetch the JSON back to your client application, and use code to explode the JSON array and concatenate it.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a JSON to CSV transformation using the keys rather than the values. The real "problem" is the usage of the keys, but it's achievable in a less hacky way. I don't think this is any less hacky, but you might find it more elegant. And just to be extra sure: No, there isn't anything in MySQL that natively does what you need.

```sql
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(json_source.a_key SEPARATOR '|') 
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    JSON_KEYS('{
        "foo": "I am foo",
        "bar": "I am bar",
        "baz": "I am baz"
        }'), 
    "$[*]" COLUMNS(a_key TEXT PATH '$')
  ) AS json_source;
```

[`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) is a potent tool, but it takes a fair bit of reading and a lot of pillow talk to understand. I'm in the pillow talk phase myself. [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) works as you'd expect, but vertically.

EDIT: Also read for reference this [somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72196812/mysql-json-key-value-pair-to-table).